# Selenide. Отметить Checkbox

Tags: checkbox, selenide

Помогите пожалуйста, в тесте надо нажать чекбокс.
Пробовал такие варианты:

```
$("[data-test-id='registrationDealerForm_vat_payer']").setSelected(true);
//Only use setSelected on checkbox/option/radio
$("[data-test-id='registrationDealerForm_vat_payer']").click();
//Element not found {[data-test-id='registrationDealerForm_tax_identification_number']}
//Expected: visible or transparent: visible or have css value opacity=0
$("[id='vat_payer47']").setSelected(true);
//нельзя
$("[name='vat_payer']").click();
//Invalid element state: element not interactable
$(By.className("vac-player")).click();
//Element not found {By.className: vac-player}
//Expected: visible or transparent: visible or have css value opacity=0
$(".vat_payer").click();
//Element not found {.vat_payer}
//Expected: visible or transparent: visible or have css value opacity=0
$(".registrationDealerForm_vat_payer").click();
//Element not found {.registrationDealerForm_vat_payer}
//Expected: visible or transparent: visible or have css value opacity=0
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='vat_payer']").click();
//Invalid element state: element not interactable
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='vat_payer']").setSelected(true); 
//Invalid element state: Cannot change invisible element
```

Вот пациент

```
<div class="InputBlock__InputBlockWrapper-sc-9h1ybp-0 bdxznE">
<div class="sc-bwzfXH RegistrationDealerGrid__RegistrationDealerRow-sc-1u8aodb-0 hWVnLj">
<div class="sc-htpNat RegistrationDealerGrid__RegistrationDealerCol-sc-1u8aodb-1 eVAsbM">
<div class="InputContainer-sc-104wwb9-0 PageRegistrationDealer__VatCheckboxInputContainer-c9kvwz-5 fbmcRU">
<div data-test-id="registrationDealerForm_vat_payer" data-test-value="false" class="Checkbox__FormFieldWrapper-wku8vo-0 Checkbox__Wrapper-wku8vo-3 gerPkX">
<input type="checkbox" id="vat_payer267" name="vat_payer" value="" class="Checkbox__Input-wku8vo-2 fugwTE">
<label for="vat_payer267" class="FormLabel-sc-1vmo8o0-0 Checkbox__Label-wku8vo-1 iETRHw">I'm a VAT payer</label></div></div></div></div></div>
```

id="vat_payer267" - плохой вариант, так как цифра меняется с каждым обновлением страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[data-test-id='registrationDealerForm_vat_payer'] label").click();
```